# How to execute multiple commands from an input file and string it to a new output file

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, csv, string

I want to execute multiple commands (one after the other) from an input.txt file and output it to a new .csv file. 
All the commands run successfully when executed individually, but nothing happens when I run them together with { && or ; }

my commands are:

```
cat input_file.txt > output_file.csv
   awk 'NR % 13 == 0' 
   sed -i '1i id,surface area (mm^2),gray matter volume (mm^3),avg
   cortical thickness +-sd,mean curvature,gaussian curvature,folding
   index,curvature index,hemi,ROI' 
   awk -F"/" '$1=$1' OFS="\t" 
   sed -e 's/\s\+/,/g' 
   awk '{ print $10 " " $0}'   >> output_file.csv
```

Does somebody know how I can run all of these commands together with each command being executed after the previous command?
Thanks so much!

Comment: this is a good Q! still a bit unclear..."one after the other"...well can you show how you use these _individually_? I just realise I can't really make sense of this CHAIN of simple commands. And with a design like that you have TWO inputs: code and data. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to *chain* the output from one to the input for the next? If yes, then you should "chain" your commands with pipes. That makes the output from the first program become the input for the next one:

```
date -u
```

mar oct 15 17:58:20 UTC 2019

```
date -u | sed 's/ /./'
```

mar.oct.15.17:58:20.UTC.2019

So, you could run *one after the other* by chaining them with the pipe character |

Alternatively, if you want to get the output from all of them independently, you can use a subshell. In bash, you would do something like this:

```
(command1.sh;command2.sh;command3.sh) >> output.txt
```

Note that you can use ';', '&&', a newline or anything meant to run the separate the commands.

Comment: I agree! So you too do not see an obvious way to "pipe" these sed and awk lines together? I do not know them well. That first awk line _per se_...would it do what if you give it something? `awk 'NR % 13 == 0'` is that line 13,26,39,...and then what???

Comment: Well your last sentence is a bit shaky ;)  _...run the separate the commands_